# I have a CSV file and I am trying to extract data using python. Not getting correct results. Can someone help? Code and sample data attached

Tags: python, csv

The simple python code opens a file, sample attached and extracts all the rows corresponding to all users in their respective. However, its not working properly. Note that the file is sorted according to USERS.

```
queries_file = file("queries_new_distinct_sorted.csv")
old_user = None
current_user = None
user_file = None
queries = "" # variable to capture all the rows as \n separated string
for line in queries_file:
    query, user, timestamp, categories = line.strip().split(",")
    # to extract component from the csv file

    current_user = user

    if old_user == None:
        old_user = current_user         
        queries += timestamp +","+ categories+"\n"

    elif old_user != current_user:
        if len(queries.strip().split('\n')) > 3:            
            user_file = open("users/" + old_user,'w+')
            user_file.write(queries)
            user_file.close() 
            old_user = current_user
            queries = timestamp +","+ categories+"\n"

    else:       
        queries += timestamp +","+ categories+"\n"


queries_file.close()
```

File :

```
ipd,6086533,2006-05-12_19:45:23,shopping/vehicles/parts and accessories
tire rack,6086533,2006-05-13_22:29:44,shopping/vehicles/parts and accessories
volvo r 70 speed parts,6086533,2006-05-14_23:04:33,shopping/vehicles/autos
puerto rico,6086589,2006-03-07_21:39:36,travel and tourism/travel guides
espn spanish,6086589,2006-03-12_19:53:26,world/español/medios de comunicación
```

Comment: What's the actual issue that you're having?

Comment: What is the expected output ?

Comment: The expected output is : all the transactions of same user should go into a file of his user-id.

Comment: The problem is : It is not capturing all the users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. 
I was not resetting values in case if length of queries was less than 2.